# Find the software that create a folder

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer

Every 5 seconds, a new folder with the name `MSI*.tmp` is created at my `c:`.

1 seconde before, this folder is deleted.

How can I know who is creating this folder. Can it be a virus?

[image]

Comment: Domain machine? Any installs going?

Comment: Fire up [SysInternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and try to capture the ```msiexec.exe``` process that's running every 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes, this is a domain machine... This is happening for 3 days... Windows is not showing the update icon...

Comment: I would contact your IT support staff.

Answer (score 8):

Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from Microsoft (originally SysInternals). It will give you a ton of output, but you can filter on your folder name.

Comment: Thanks, i run the `process monitor` and the program that is creating this folder is the `msiexec.exe`, how can i know what is driving this execution?

Comment: I would dig in with `Process Monitor` and see if there is any more useful information. One thing to try: double-click one of the lines that contains `msiexec.exe`. You should see "Event Properties". Switch to the "Process" tab and look at "Command Line". This may contain the path to the program it is trying to install. Also, the advice above to talk to your IT staff is really good. It is possible this is malicious software, but even if it is well-meaning software, it's still doing bad things to you.

Comment: Look into your Windows log, MSI installs are usually logged there, and you'll be able to find out what product is installed.